# Meteor deploying on Modulus

Tags: mongodb, meteor, modulus.io

Modulus deployments is perfect without any problems, but is not working. I have created a database on Modulus with the same name on the Meteor app.

http://wikimicroscope-13216.onmodulus.net/

Console log in Modulus:

```
Error: URL must be in the format mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at exports.parse (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/url_parser.js:15:11)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:164:16)
    at Function.Db.connect (/mnt/data/2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:2035:23)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:151)
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo-livedata/remote_collection_driver.js:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo-livedata/remote_collection_driver.js:44)
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore/underscore.js:750)
    at new Meteor.Collection (packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:72)
    at packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:122
[2014-05-23T16:02:46.435Z] Application CRASH detected. Exit code 8.
[2014-05-23T16:02:47.472Z] Application restarted.
```

I have set `mongo_url` and `root_url` before. Here are my environment variables:

```
CONNECTION STRINGS
MONGO URI
mongodb://<user>:<pass>@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/iZ3anope
MONGO CONSOLE
mongo novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/iZ3anope -u <user> -p <pass>
```

I have deployed with different node versions like v0.10.25, v0.10.28. It is not working.

Beside on the browser there is the messages:

```
!Unable to connect to any application instances.!
```

and in the console inspector in Chrome / local store I find a message like this:

```
BiDefender_BLock {"verdict":"TRACKER","hitList":""}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are your env variable names all uppercase?

Comment: Thanks for answer me, and yes I have enviroments variables name in uppercase, I deployed in meteor without any problems but with modulus i can't do it: NODE_ENV = production
MONGO_URL =  mongodb://user:password@novus.modulusmongo.net:27017/iZ3anope
ROOT_URL = http://wikimicroscope-13216.onmodulus.net

Comment: Need solution too, same issue after deploy with right env variables...

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill in `<user>:<pass>` with the username and password you set for the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and solve it by executing:

`modulus env set MONGO_URL "mongodb://myUser:myPass@proximus.modulusmongo.net:27017/6sd54f5f?autoReconnect=true&connectTimeoutMS=60000"`

instead of:

`modulus env set MONGO_URL "mongodb://myUser:myPass@proximus.modulusmongo.net:27017/6sd54f5f ?autoReconnect=true&connectTimeoutMS=60000"`

If you see, I added an extra space before the '?'

When I look at logs in modulus web interface, it told me database name cannot contains character ' ' (space)

Answer (score 0):

I also just had this problem and fixed it by restarting my app